# Big database and how to proceed

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I'm working on a website running ASP.NET with MSSQL Database. I realized, that the number of rows in several tables can be very high (possibly something like hundread million rows). I thnik, that this would make the website run very slowly, am I right?

How should I proceed? Should I base it on a multidatabase system, so that users will be separated in different databases and each of the databases will be smaller? Or is there a different, more effective and easier approach?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Start by indexing properly and only returning relevant results sets. Consider archiving unused data (or rarely accessed data).

Answer (score 1):

Oded's comment is a good starting point and you may be able to just stop there.

> Start by indexing properly and only returning relevant results sets. Consider archiving unused data (or rarely accessed data

However if it isn't [Partioning or Sharding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms345146%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) is your next step. This is better than a "multidatabase" solution because your logical entities remain intact.

Finally if that doesn't work you could introduce caching. Jesper Mortensen gives a [nice summary](https://serverfault.com/questions/95695/memcached-on-windows-x64/121996#121996) of the options that are out there for SQL Server

> - [Sharedcache](http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/) -- open source, mature.
> - [Appfabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx) -- from Microsoft, quite mature despite being "late
>     beta".
> - [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) -- commercial, I don't know much about it.
> - [StateServer](http://www.scaleoutsoftware.com/) and family -- commercial, mature.

Answer (score 0):

Try partitioning the data. This should make each query faster and the website shouldn't be as slow

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of data you'll be displaying, but try to give users the option to filter it. As someone had already commented, partitioned data will make everything faster.